# /etc/network/interfaces automatically startup pppoe on wireless lan (wlan0) on boot and also make it persistent

Tags: networking, wifi, startup

I do have the following setting OK in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto wlan0
auto dsl-provider

iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.XXX.XXX
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.XXX.255
wpa-ssid   <MY-SSID>
wpa-psk    <MY-Password>

iface dsl-provider inet ppp
provider dsl-provider
```

The last two lines are inserted by my previous execution of `/usr/sbin/pppoeconf wlan0`

However, `auto dsl-provider` does not work well.  The dsl-dialer won't start on boot. What can I do to make dsl-dialer startup on boot?

Also, how to make this link persistent? I mean, when the link is down, retry bringing it up.  This may includes bringing up of both `wlan0` and `dsl-provider`.